# Link retrieve data (from SQL server) query to LUIS Intent. Code issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I want to retrieve data from a SQL server data table and link each retrieving request to a specific LUIS intent.

In the illustration bellow, I try to retrieve data from the contractual power data table.

```
[Serializable]
public class BasicLuisDialog : LuisDialog<object>
{

    public BasicLuisDialog() : base(new LuisService(new LuisModelAttribute(
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LuisAppId"],
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LuisAPIKey"],
        domain: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LuisAPIHostName"])))
    {
    }
    //Constants

    // Intents
    public const string IntentContractualPower = "SearchContractualPower";
    public const string IntentNone = "None";

    // Entities
    public const string EntityEAN = "EAN";
    public const string EntityBeginDate = "BeginDate";

    // Entities found in result
    public string BotEntityRecognition(LuisResult result)
    {
        StringBuilder entityResults = new StringBuilder();

        if (result.Entities.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (EntityRecommendation item in result.Entities)
            {
                entityResults.Append(item.Type + "=" + item.Entity + ",");
            }
            // remove last comma
            entityResults.Remove(entityResults.Length - 1, 1);
        }

        return entityResults.ToString();
    }

    [LuisIntent("SearchContractualPower")]
    public async Task ContractualPowerIntent(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        await ContractualPower(context, result);
    }

    private Task ContractualPower(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void ContractualPower(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            builder.DataSource = "X";
            builder.UserID = "X";
            builder.Password = "X";
            builder.InitialCatalog = "ChatBot_EDWErrors";

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
            {

                connection.Open();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Append("SELECT ErrorDescription FROM [err].[ErrorFactContractualPower]");
                sb.Append(" WHERE EAN = ");
                sb.Append(EntityEAN);
                sb.Append(" AND BeginDate = ");
                sb.Append(EntityEAN);

                String sql = sb.ToString();

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("{0}", reader.GetString(0));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
        }
        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    [LuisIntent("None")]
    public async Task NoneIntent(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        await this.ShowLuisResult(context, result);
    }

    private async Task ShowLuisResult(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        // get recognized entities
        string entities = this.BotEntityRecognition(result);

        // round number
        string roundedScore = result.Intents[0].Score != null ? (Math.Round(result.Intents[0].Score.Value, 2).ToString()) : "0";

        await context.PostAsync($"**Query**: {result.Query}, **Intent**: {result.Intents[0].Intent}, **Score**: {roundedScore}. **Entities**: {entities}");
        context.Wait(MessageReceived);
    }
}
```

Yet I can't get it to work [see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8WCW.png). FYI, I am writing the code directly on the online code editor on the web bot app, the later is build on the Microsoft Azure platform.

How can I fix this?

Thank you

Comment: Did you look at the logfiles from the Kudu console? In the editor, select second item in top blue bar, then get to "Open Kudu Console". Also, did you test your request from the LUIS endpoint and know that works?

Comment: @DFBerry I haven't used the 'Kudu console' before but I did at your recommendation. I opened all the files on it but couldn't find something helpful. 
Also, I tested both the Luis end points and the SQL query separately, they both work. Yet when I tried to add the SQL query to the LUIS code, that's when the issue happened.

Comment: You have two `ContractualPower` functions written. One has `NotImplementedException` and other has the `SQL code`. Well the function that's called from LUIS intent function is `await ContractualPower(context, result);`, clearly the not implemented function. Change your 'NotImplementedException()' function to the actual logic and test it.

Comment: You can check the errors by clicking the "Issues" link for the affected channel on [bot's Channels blade](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-manage-channels?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#get-started). Besides, if you test your bot with webchat, you can check response status&error details via browser network tool. And if possible, you can [install VS and Bot Builder SDK](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-3.0), then download your source code and debug on local to troubleshoot the issue.